# Storing data in core data

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data

I have an excel file of words and definitions. I would like to use core data to have these words and definitions that when a word is clicked the definition comes up.

Right now I am stuck on how to go about bringing in my words and definitions. Do I just create an array and have words and definitions? Do I need a server to host? The only tutorials I find are how to instantly create things and put them in core data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: How to Populate CoreData with downloaded CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613271/ios-how-to-populate-coredata-with-downloaded-csv)

Comment: Find yourself a good core data tutorial, and combined with the link above for repopulating from a CSV you should be good to go.  Generally speaking you can find good tutorials at https://www.raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a server for core data.  But you can also just create a dictionary to accomplish your goal.

Comment: okay. how do I do this? It's actually a lot of words which was why I was looking at parse to hold everything

Comment: Sure, Parse is great, and although it is shut down you can still use it open source.  Deploy Parse to Heroku using the purple button in this link - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku - set up your server and your good to go.  Alternatively you can use a dictionary  or array without a server.  Check out this info on Dictionaries, i think it'll help - https://www.weheartswift.com/dictionaries/

Comment: If there are a substantial number of entries, a dictionary probably isn't the appropriate answer.  She's on a better track with CoreData.

Comment: I agree with that, it definitely depends on the number of entries.